# Console.WriteLine to Response.Write?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I am in a WebForm, and I'd like to use the common Console.Writeline with this format:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}:", myString, myProp);
```

with Response.Write (putting code on client side). Can I?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, yes you can use `Response.Write`, but `Console.WriteLine` won't go anywhere (apart from 'Output' when debugging). If you're asking about the format specifically, use `Response.Write(String.Format("{0}{1}:", myString, myProp));`.

Comment: @RudiVisser - he wants the same behaviour as Console.WriteLine i am not famlier with asp but i guess, `Response.Write(string format, params object[] args)` dont exists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The using of `Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}:", myString, myProp);` doesn't make sense in this case, but you can use the [`string.Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.format.aspx) method:

```
Response.Write(string.Format("{0}{1}:", myString, myProp));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can write a Method like

```
public static void WriteToResponse(string format, params object[] args)
{
    Response.Write(String.Format(format, args));
}
```

The above method is `Console` equivalent of `Console.Write` you can add a extra `Response.Write(Environment.NewLine)` to make it similar to `Console.WriteLine`

```
public static void WriteLineToResponse(string format, params object[] args)
{
    Response.Write(String.Format(format, args));
    Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Response.Write (string.Format("{0}{1}:", myString, myProp));
```

Or make a extention method for Response.Write with string, object[] as arguments.